# how to place star rating image next to the textlabel

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

i m parsing json feed and according to the parsed value i m placing star images in table view cell.what i want is to place the star rating images as soon as the no of words in the textlabel gets completed the star rating images got to be flexible and not to have fixed frame. below is the code and screenshot of how the output got to look like.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

//[tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
HJManagedImageV* mi;
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    mi = [[[HJManagedImageV alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-18,-2,90,90)] autorelease];
    mi.tag = 999;
    [cell addSubview:mi];
}
else
{
    mi=(HJManagedImageV *)[cell viewWithTag:999];
    [mi clear];
}

NSDictionary *boy=[self.media1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",boy];
NSInteger n=[str intValue];
NSLog(@"the value:%@",str);

if(n ==0)
{   
    CGRect starFrame = CGRectMake(100,6, 85, 40);

    UIImageView *starImage = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:starFrame] autorelease];
    starImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"nostar.png"];
    starImage.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:starImage];

    NSString *boo=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%d",n];
    NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"(%@)",boo];
    CGRect labelFrame = CGRectMake(290,18, 40, 40);
    UILabel *Label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame] autorelease];

    Label.text=str;
    Label.tag=1000;
  //  Label.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:Label];


}
if(n >=1)
{   
    CGRect starFrame = CGRectMake(100,6, 85, 40);

    UIImageView *starImage = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:starFrame] autorelease];
    starImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1star.png"];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:starImage];

    NSString *boo=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%d",n];
    CGRect labelFrame = CGRectMake(290,18, 40, 40);
    UILabel *Label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame] autorelease];
    NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"(%@)",boo];
    Label.text=str;
    Label.tag=1000;
   //Label.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:Label];

}

if(n >=2)
{   
    CGRect starFrame = CGRectMake(100,6, 85, 40);

    UIImageView *starImage = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:starFrame] autorelease];
    starImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"twostar.png"];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:starImage];

    NSString *boo=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%d",n];
      NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"(%@)",boo];
    CGRect labelFrame = CGRectMake(290,18, 40,40);
    UILabel *Label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame] autorelease];
    Label.text=str;
    Label.tag=1000;
   // Label.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:Label];

}
 if(n >=3)
{   
    CGRect starFrame = CGRectMake(100,6, 85, 40);

    UIImageView *starImage = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:starFrame] autorelease];
    starImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"threestar.png"];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:starImage];

    NSString *boo=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%d",n];
    NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"(%@)",boo];
    CGRect labelFrame = CGRectMake(290,18, 40,40);
    UILabel *Label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame] autorelease];
    Label.text=str;
    Label.tag=1000;
   Label.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:Label];

}

  if(n >= 4)
{
    CGRect starFrame = CGRectMake(100,6, 85, 40);

    UIImageView *starImage = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:starFrame] autorelease];
    starImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"4star.png"];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:starImage];

    NSString *boo=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%d",n];
     NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"(%@)",boo];
    CGRect labelFrame = CGRectMake(290,18,40,40);
    UILabel *Label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame] autorelease];
    Label.text=str;
    Label.tag=1000;
   //Label.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:Label];
}
if(n >= 5)
{
    CGRect starFrame = CGRectMake(100,6, 85, 40);

    UIImageView *starImage = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:starFrame] autorelease];
    starImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"5star.png"];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:starImage];

    NSString *boo=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%d",n];
    NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"(%@)",boo];
    CGRect labelFrame = CGRectMake(290,18, 40,40);
    UILabel *Label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame] autorelease];
    Label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18];
    Label.text=str;
    Label.tag=1000;
  // Label.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:Label];
}

cell.textLabel.text=[self.story objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines=2;

return cell;

 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try out this code, i have solved

```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //[tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    HJManagedImageV* mi;
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
//    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        mi = [[[HJManagedImageV alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-18,-2,90,90)] autorelease];
        mi.tag = 999;
        [cell addSubview:mi];
    cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    CGSize sizeTitle = [[self.story objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0] 
                            constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(200, 40) 
                                lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    float width = sizeTitle.width;
    NSLog(@"Width %f", width);
    width = width+15;
    NSDictionary *boy=[self.media1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",boy];
    NSInteger n=[str intValue];
    NSLog(@"the value:%@",str);
    CGRect coreFrame;
    if(width<170){
        coreFrame = CGRectMake(2, 6, width, 40);
    }
    else{
        coreFrame = CGRectMake(2, 6, 170, 40);   
        width = 175;
    }
     float k = width+85;
    UILabel *lab = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:coreFrame];
    lab.text = [self.story objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:lab];

    if(n ==0)
    {   
        CGRect starFrame = CGRectMake(width,6, 85, 37);

        UIImageView *starImage = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:starFrame] autorelease];
        starImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"nostar.png"];
        starImage.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:starImage];

        NSString *boo=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%d",n];
        NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"(%@)",boo];
       // str=[str substringToIndex:4];
        CGRect labelFrame = CGRectMake(k,6, 40, 40);
        UILabel *Label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame] autorelease];

        Label.text=str;
        Label.tag=1000;
          Label.textColor=[UIColor grayColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:Label];


    }
    if(n >=1)
    {   
        CGRect starFrame = CGRectMake(width,6, 85, 37);

        UIImageView *starImage = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:starFrame] autorelease];
        starImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1star.png"];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:starImage];

        NSString *boo=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%d",n];
        CGRect labelFrame = CGRectMake(k,6, 40, 40);
        UILabel *Label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame] autorelease];
        NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"(%@)",boo];
        Label.text=str;
        Label.tag=1000;
          Label.textColor=[UIColor grayColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:Label];
    }
    if(n >=2)
    {   
        CGRect starFrame = CGRectMake(width,6, 85, 37);

        UIImageView *starImage = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:starFrame] autorelease];
        starImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"twostar.png"];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:starImage];

        NSString *boo=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%d",n];
          NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"(%@)",boo];
        CGRect labelFrame = CGRectMake(k,6, 40,40);
        UILabel *Label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame] autorelease];
               Label.text=str;
        Label.tag=1000;
          Label.textColor=[UIColor grayColor];
       // Label.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:Label];
    }
     if(n >=3)
    {   
        CGRect starFrame = CGRectMake(width,6, 85, 37);

        UIImageView *starImage = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:starFrame] autorelease];
        starImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"threestar.png"];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:starImage];

        NSString *boo=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%d",n];
        NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"(%@)",boo];
      //  str=[str substringToIndex:4];

        CGRect labelFrame = CGRectMake(k,6, 40,40);
        UILabel *Label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame] autorelease];

        Label.text=str;
        Label.tag=1000;
          Label.textColor=[UIColor grayColor];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:Label];

    }
   if(n >= 4)
    {
        CGRect starFrame = CGRectMake(width,6, 85, 37);

        UIImageView *starImage = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:starFrame] autorelease];
        starImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"4star.png"];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:starImage];

        NSString *boo=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%d",n];
         NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"(%@)",boo];
        //str=[str substringToIndex:4];

        CGRect labelFrame = CGRectMake(k,6,40,40);
        UILabel *Label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame] autorelease];

        Label.text=str;
        Label.tag=1000;
        Label.textColor=[UIColor grayColor];
       //Label.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:Label];
    }
    if(n >= 5)
    {
        CGRect starFrame = CGRectMake(width,6, 85, 37);

        UIImageView *starImage = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:starFrame] autorelease];
        starImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"5star.png"];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:starImage];

        NSString *boo=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%d",n];
        NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"(%@)",boo];
       // str=[str substringToIndex:4];

        CGRect labelFrame = CGRectMake(k,6, 40,40);
        UILabel *Label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame] autorelease];
        Label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18];

        Label.text=str;
        Label.tag=1000;
        Label.textColor=[UIColor grayColor];
      // Label.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:Label];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method to calculate the width and height of a string --

– sizeWithFont:
– sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode:
– sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:
– sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:
– sizeWithFont:minFontSize:actualFontSize:forWidth:lineBreakMode:

or you can refer the doc here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html

on the basis of width you need to set your label width and then set the frame of your star image.

an example -

```
CGSize sizeTitle = [titleStr sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0] 
                                       constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(200, 40) 
                                           lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

float width = sizeTitle.width;
```

Comment: could u gimme an small example based on the above code to place the images..will be greatful

Comment: consider updating the condition if(n<=5) should i remove the CGRect starFrame

Comment: could u add two more lines of adding the image with above width.. i m a noob